# How to filter URL on the bases of web domain?

Tags: java, string, url, optimization

I have set of urls now i want to filter them out on the bases of web domains(say wikipedia urls).
Right now what i am doing is iterating set and for each url i am just finding a keyword of that web address.

```
 if(ur.contains("wikipedia.org")){
    //do something
 }
```

is there any other technique that is more efficient than my current approach?

Comment: What's wring with this way ? Seems ok to me

Comment: @RahulTripathi not efficient, because it's not work in URL: www.somesite.com/index.html?id=wikipedia.org

Comment: @viartemev yes you are right, url sometimes also contain the string on the basis of which i am trying to filter out.

Comment: @aniketsiva you can use my solution below

Comment: As per the discussion its not correct just to seek the domain string in url, rather we need to get domain as per viartemev's solution. I also did this mistake. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if("wikipedia.org".equals(getDomainName(ur))){
    //do something
 }

public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying do do with :
    domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;

Comment: @aniketsiva sometime getHost return www.somehost.org instead somehost.org. And this code always returns somehost.org

Answer (score 0):

Viartemev's answer is good if you need to get full domain (e.g. someinfo.wikipedia.org)
If you want to get top level domain only (e.g. wikipedia.org) then .contains() is the best approach

```
if(url.contains("wikipedia.org")){
    domain = wikipedia.org"
 }
```